# Can't Unresolved reference Bigdecimal. But I added ExtendedScalars

Tags: kotlin, netflix-dgs

i have some problem when i use netflix dgs.

I added some type ExtendsScalar

```
@DgsComponent
class ScalarExtendRegistration {
    @DgsRuntimeWiring
    fun addScalar(builder: RuntimeWiring.Builder): RuntimeWiring.Builder {
        return builder.scalar(ExtendedScalars.Date)
                      .scalar(ExtendedScalars.DateTime)
                      .scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong)
                      .scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLBigDecimal)
    }
}
```

Date, DateTime, GraphpQLLong.. It's well-generated.

But GraphQLBigDecimal.. I checked in this generated code - Unresolved reference: BigDecimal. Because it is not automatically imported.

```
  @JsonProperty("id")
  public val id: Long? = null,
  @JsonProperty("insertedAt")
  public val insertedAt: LocalDate? = null,
  @JsonProperty("updatedAt")
  public val updatedAt: LocalDate? = null,
  @JsonProperty("secret")
  public val secret: String? = null,
  @JsonProperty("name")
  public val name: String? = null,
  @JsonProperty("nickName")
  public val nickName: String? = null,
  @JsonProperty("address")
  public val address: String? = null,
  @JsonProperty("money")
  public val money: BigDecimal? = null
) {
  public companion object
}
```

here is my netflixe dgs dependency version

```
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen:graphql-dgs-codegen-client-core:5.0.6
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-client:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-extended-scalars:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-mocking:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-oss-autoconfigure:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-webmvc:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-webmvc-autoconfigure:4.7.3
Gradle: com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-error-types:4.7.3
```

I wonder why BigDecimal is not automatically imported.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your gradle file and it will work

```
generateJava{
    typeMapping = ["BigDecimal":"java.math.BigDecimal"]
}
```